# Unknown MOSFET symbol

Tags: mosfet, pmos

I came across the schematic symbol shown, and I am unsure of what the symbol in the green box is. It looks like a PMOS (yellow box), but it has the line before the gate. Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this symbol? Was it printed or hand drawn like the one you show? Was the extra line connected to anything? I don't recognize it and it seems pretty strange to add an extra line like that. Maybe it's just someone who made a mistake, or have deleted something that was connected to the gate without removing the entire line.

Comment: It really is a strange symbol. If there were also the other components connected to this MOSFET it would be more interesting and maybe easier to understand. For now the only thing I can think of is the possibility of a PMOS with double gate.

Comment: Please explain why you think it's strange and why you think it's PMOS. Please also show the original rendition of what you saw rather than your impression of what you saw.

Comment: Could be just an input connection labeled D1, D2, Dn

Comment: I considered that, yes - but figured I would post a question to see if anyone else had any other thoughts.

Comment: @user1187621 No, that's a connection note. You need to find the Dn's elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those FETs are both nMOS transistors, drawn in the CMOS schematic style. This is the style that you're likely to see (both hand-drawn and printed) in a course on integrated analog CMOS design.

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.circuitlab.com/blog/2013/10/17/new-mosfet-schematic-symbols/)</sup>

If this is on an integrated process, chances are the transistors are symmetric with body connections made to the shared substrate, so it's not *necessarily* correct to conclude that the arrow is at the source and the other side is the drain.

The "line before the gate" is just an input signal, which may look weird simply because there isn't a lot of room to space out the schematic. The other end of the connection is not shown on this schematic, and is likely a control signal from some other part of the schematic, or another schematic in the same paper/document.